# link_to inherits informations from other link_to in the same file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

If I specify controller and action for a link_to, the other one returns

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/users", :username=>"username"}

It seems to be using the controller and the action provided to the previous link_to and it does this wherever i place the first line.

```
<li><%= link_to 'Profile', {:controller => "users", :action => "show", :username => current_user.username} %></li>
<li><%= link_to('Edit Account', edit_user_registration_path )%></li>
```

Relevant portion of rake routes:

```
                       GET    /users/:username(.:format)       users#show
edit_user_registration GET    /account/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show the relevant portion of `rake routes` output

Comment: The right parenthesis on 'Edit Account' is missing.

Comment: Why not just do `<li><%= link_to('Profile', user_path(current_user, :username => current_user.username) %></li>`?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Baldrick I'm sorry, it's there in my code. I missed it here. Edited.

Comment: @CDub Thank you. I added `<%= link_to('Profile', user_path(:username => current_user.username)) %>` and modified routes adding `:as => :user` and now it works :) but I still can't explain myself why with the previous method there's this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use url_for when going the controller/action/param way for the route like that so the correct syntax for the first link would be:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Profile', url_for(:controller => "users", :action => "show", :username => current_user.username) %></li>
```

See the api doc for reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor/url_for